# what i do with the Grade column in second normal form

Tags: mysql, database

I tried to solve this to normalize my table but confused at the column grade.There is an ambiguity about that, Can you define a hint what should i do with that

```
STUDENT (Student_number, 
         student_name, 
         number_credit, 
         professor_number, 
         professor_name, 
         Course_code, 
         Course_name, 
         **GRADE**)
```

whether in second and third normal form. I normalize in second as

```
STUDENT_NAME (Student_number, student_name)
Professor (professor_number, professor_name)
COURSE (Course_code, Course_name, number_credit)
```

Now what should i do with the **Grade** column in which table this take place or i should make a new table?

Comment: Assuming student can take many courses and professor can teach many courses then 2 junction/linking tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your relation

```
STUDENT (Student_number, student_name, number_credit, professor_number, professor_name, Course_code, Course_name, GRADE)
```

Yours answer about the others column (attributes) are correct.

```
STUDENT_NAME (Student_number, student_name) Professor (professor_number, professor_name)
COURSE (Course_code, Course_name, number_credit)
```

For me, there is this functional dependencies about *GRADE*:

```
{Student_number, Course_code} -> Grade
```

So, it's necessary to create another relation:

```
GRADES (Student_number, Course_code, Grade)
with the two firsts columns compound the primary key
```